# GitLab CI: frontend-maven-plugin error with Angular - ng: not found

Tags: node.js, angular, gitlab-ci, maven-3, frontend-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project using `Java 11`, Maven `3.6.3` where one of the modules uses [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) plugin.
When running locally on macOS, everything works fine, when running with GitLab runner it fails.
Here is the project `pom.xml` file in `my-project/app-client` folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-client</artifactId>
    <name>app-client</name>
    <description>client</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.2.3</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.13.4</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>v12.4.0</frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <frontBuild>run build</frontBuild>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <properties>
                <frontBuild>run build:test</frontBuild>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <frontBuild>run build:prod</frontBuild>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>client</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>install node</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install -g npm-install-peers</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>${frontBuild}</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-client-package</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>assembly/webclient_assembly_descr.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11

stages:
  - build_client
  - compile

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  #- npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.19 -> add to fix the error: 'ng' command was not found

build_client:
  stage: build_client
  script:
    - cd app-client/client
    - npm install

compile:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - cd app-client
    - mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

I limited the GitLab CI just for the failing module.
So there are 2 stages, the 1st is OK, but the 2 fails with:

```
[INFO] Copying node binary from /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/target/node/tmp/node-v12.4.0-linux-x64/bin/node to /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/target/node/node
[INFO] Extracting NPM
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.13.4:npm (npm install) @ app-client ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install -g npm-install-peers' in /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/client
[INFO] /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/target/bin/npm-install-peers -> /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/target/lib/node_modules/npm-install-peers/bin/npm-install-peers.js
[INFO] + npm-install-peers@1.2.2
[INFO] added 466 packages from 897 contributors in 6.431s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.13.4:npm (npm run build) @ app-client ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run build' in /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/client
[INFO] 
[INFO] > web-plage@0.0.0 build /builds/my-company/my-project/app-client/client
[INFO] > ng build
[INFO] 
[INFO] sh: 1: ng: not found
[INFO] npm ERR! file sh
...
```

Any ideas? Thank you!